# Firebase Push Notifications - how do I change the activity destination?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a push notification that indicates that a video has been uploaded successfully. What I want is to change the activity destination of the clicked notification, right now it is going to my MainActivity, but I can't figure out how to change it.

I have the FirebaseMessagingService class from the documentation but I don't understand where should I put the intent because it seems like I never reach this place -

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String RECEIVED_FCM_ACTION = "com.onemdtalent.app.RECEIVED_FCM_ACTION";

    public static final String BD_KEY_BODY = "BD_KEY_BODY";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        Timber.tag("remoteMessage").d(remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        //String image = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");

        Timber.d("onMessageReceived: %s", remoteMessage.getFrom());
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            Timber.d("Message Notification Body: %s", body);
            // broadcast
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(RECEIVED_FCM_ACTION);
            localIntent.putExtra(BD_KEY_BODY, body);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Destination activity using Pendingintent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

in your notification builder set content intent like this

```
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Where do I actually put this code inside? it should be inside the class that I posted? inside the method 'onMessageReceived()'?

Comment: inside if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {}

Comment: It seems like you are creating the entire notification from scratch. I already have a notification that is created from Firebase and I just want to re-direct it to a new location.

Comment: is on onMessageReceived called?

Comment: Not when the app is being started from the notification itself.

Answer (score 0):

You will get intent data in your MainActivity, you can take intent data and start your RedirectActivity with intent data.

get intent data in your redirect activity, and parse your data.
Hope this will work for you.

Place this type of code into your MainActivity.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,RedirectActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data",getIntent());
startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad solution. Why can't I just automatically forward it to the relevant activity?

Comment: "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"              add this key valur in your payload and                                 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter> put this lines of code into your activity in menifest file